# useRef is null when it's rendered without browser refresh

Tags: reactjs, react-router, use-effect, use-ref

So unfortunately i have problem with my component. So let's explain a little more.

I have `div` container with some content in there.
This container has `height: 100%` and `overflow-auto` style.
When the user go to the the corresponding component, it will scroll automatically to the bottom of the container.
So what's the problem then?

So the problem is when user goes to that component via `<Link> or <Redirect>` `useRef` is returning null.
I tried with `useEffect` with `ref.current` dep but still work only on page refresh and not work with `Link` and etc.

Stop talking, here's some of my code:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, useRef} from "react";
import {useTranslation} from "react-multi-lang";
import UserLayout from "../../containers/UserLayout";
import HomeLayout from "../../containers/HomeLayout";
import {useParams} from "react-router";
import {connect} from "react-redux";

const TicketAnswers = props => {
    const t = useTranslation();
    const [reply, setReply] = useState("");
    const [ticket, setTicket] = useState([]);

    const user = props.user.data
    const {id} = useParams();
    const messageDivBox = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!props.userAltData.loading) {
            setTicket(props.userAltData.data.tickets.filter(t => t.id === parseInt(id))[0])
        }

        // Scroll into the last reply
        if (messageDivBox.current !== null) {
            messageDivBox.current.scrollTop = messageDivBox.current.scrollHeight;
        }
    }, [props.userAltData.loading, messageDivBox.current]);

    const _handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    return (
        <HomeLayout>

            <UserLayout>
                <div className="flex-1">
                    <div
                        className="rounded  shadow-lg p-4 flex flex-col justify-between leading-normal">
                        <div className="font-bold text-xl mb-2 mt-2">
                            {t('user.ticket-answers')}: {ticket.name} <br/>
                        </div>
                        <hr/>
                        {/*HERE IS MY DIV WITH ref*/}
                        <div className="overflow-auto h-56" ref={messageDivBox}>
                            {(ticket.answers === undefined || ticket.answers.length === 0) ? (t("user.no-ticket-replies")) : ticket.answers.map((ans, key) => (
                                <div className="flex flex-wrap space-x-2 my-2" key={key}>
                                    <div className="max-w-full w-full lg:max-w-full">
                                        <div
                                            className="border-r border-b border-l border-gray-400 lg:border-l-0 lg:border-t lg:border-gray-400 bg-white rounded-b lg:rounded-b-none lg:rounded-r p-4 flex flex-col justify-between leading-normal">
                                            <div className="mb-8">
                                                <p className="text-gray-700 text-base">
                                                    {ans.content}
                                                </p>
                                            </div>
                                            <hr/>
                                            <div className="flex mb-2 mt-4">
                                                <img className="w-10 h-10 rounded-full mr-4"
                                                     src={`https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/${user.email}`}
                                                     alt={`Avatar of ${user.name}`}/>
                                                <div className="text-sm">
                                                    <p className="text-gray-900 leading-none">{user.id === ans.user_id ? user.name : ans.user.name}</p>
                                                    <p className="text-gray-600">{ans.created_at}</p>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            ))}
                        </div>
                        <hr/>
                        <div className="mt-2 mb-2 lg:min-w-full">
                            <textarea className="w-full text-black" onChange={e => setReply(e.target.value)}/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </UserLayout>
        </HomeLayout>
    )

}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        user: state.user,
        userAltData: state.userAltData
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(TicketAnswers);
```

So what i do wrongh. Please give me some suggestions or tips. Thanks in advice guys!

**EDIT 1:**

I make a function with the same logic as in `useEffect()`
and then added `onLoad` event on my `<div>` to run that custom function and it works. If you know some other ways please let me see

Example:

```
const scrollToBottom = () => {
    // Scroll into the last reply
    if (messageDivBox.current !== null) {
        messageDivBox.current.scrollTop = messageDivBox.current.scrollHeight;
    }
    return true;
}

return (<div onLoad={scrollToBottom}>...content</div>);
```